# how to set minimum password of 8 characters in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am just trying to set a minimum password of 8 characters in a text box in jquery.  This is what I have so far but it just does not work:

```
    $(function() {
var passwordLength = $('#password').val().length;


 if(passwordLength < 8) {
     $('#password').next('.error').css('display', 'inline');
 } 

 }); 

 $('#password').change(function() {
 $(this).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The check for the length should be inside onchange event. 
Moving it inside, should work :

```
$(function() {

 var passwordInput = $('#password').change(function() {

   var passwordLength = passwordInput.val().length;
   var errorDisplay = (passwordLength < 8)?'inline':'none';

   passwordInput.next('.error').css('display', errorDisplay);

 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#password').on('keyup',function(){
        var Password = $(this).val();
        if (Password.length < 8){
            $('#password').next('.error').css('display', 'inline');
        }else{
            $(this).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
        }
   });
});
```